# my result in email just display "resource id#7"

Tags: php, html, mysql, email, phpmailer

I need to send my code result to the mail. 
If I write html code, its all displayed in my email, but if I write php code- its not displayed.

In my browser it works, but in my email it just displays "resource id#7".

```
<?php

include_once("include.php");
include_once("p_bulan.php");
require_once('class.phpmailer.php');

$runSQL = "select a.id_client, a.nama_cpw, ifnull(a.tlp_mobile_cpw,'belum-diinput')tlp_mobile_cpw, ifnull(a.nama_cpp,'belum-diinput')nama_cpp, ifnull(a.tlp_mobile_cpp,'belum-diinput')tlp_mobile_cpp, a.tgl_rencana, b.tgl_janjiawal, b.tgl_janjiakhir, b.barang, b.keterangan, ifnull(c.nama,'-')nama
 from client a 
 left join jadwal_fitting_new b on a.id_client=b.id_client 
 left join pegawai c on a.id_pegawai=c.id_pegawai
 where a.id_client=b.id_client and b.tgl_janjiakhir BETWEEN '$tanggal' AND '$tanggal2'
order by id_client desc";

$mail  = new PHPMailer(); // defaults to using php "mail()"

$mail->IsSendmail(); // telling the class to use SendMail transport

$body  = 

$res=mysql_query($runSQL);
//echo $runSQL;
while($rec=mysql_fetch_array($res))
{


    $ccc++;
    if ($ccc%2 > 0){ $color='#EBEFFA'; }else{ $color='#D7E0F4'; };
echo "<table><tr bgcolor=$color onmouseover=bgColor=\'#FDD0D8\' onmouseout=bgColor=\'$color\' valign=top>
    <td align='center'>".($ccc)."</td>


          <td align=center> $rec[nama_cpw] </td>
          <td align=center> $rec[tlp_mobile_cpw]</td>
          <td align=center> $rec[nama_cpp] </td>
          <td align=center> $rec[tlp_mobile_cpp] </td>
          <td align=center> $rec[tgl_rencana] </td>
          <td align=center> $rec[tgl_janjiawal] </td>
          <td align=center> $rec[tgl_janjiakhir] </td>
          <td> $rec[barang] </td>
          <td> $rec[keterangan] </td> 
          <td> $rec[nama]</td>

</tr>";
}
echo "<tr bgcolor=$color onmouseover=bgColor=\'#FDD0D8\' onmouseout=bgColor=\'$color\' valign=top>

</tr>
</table>
</font>
</table></br>

<table align='center' width='1002' height='79' border='0'>
  <tr align='center' >
    <td height='23'>Dibuat oleh,</td>
    <td>Diperikasa oleh,</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height='23'>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr align='center'>
    <td height='23'>(Admin Fitting)</td>
    <td>(KaBag. Gudang)</td>
  </tr>
</table>";



  $mail->AddReplyTo('admin@alfin.com', 'admin');
  $mail->AddAddress('alfin@gmail.com', 'zalfinm');
  $mail->SetFrom('admin@alfin.com', 'admin');
  $mail->AddReplyTo('admin@alfin.com', 'admin');
  $mail->Subject = 'test';
  $mail->AltBody = 'ini isi email'; // optional - MsgHTML will create an alternate automatically
  $mail->MsgHTML($body);


if(!$mail->Send()) {
  echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
  echo "Message sent!";
}

?>



   please help me
```

Comment: You aren't setting the $body variable to anything. You should be seeing a parser error. If not, turn error reporting on.

Comment: I've try to add code like this

$body="<table> 
    <tr bgcolor='#A7A7A7' height='25'>
   <td width='4%' align='center'>NO</td>
   <td width='12%' align='center'>NAMA CPW</td>
   bla bla bla
            <td width='10%' align='center'>PETUGAS CS</td>
</tr>".

this is the result with   . and ; 

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3Qvtu0pSBzdMTZMRXlBQ1MxZU0/view?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gw8N8PZALQ_f4RLojocliOptTuejyiNqNg/view?usp=sharing

Comment: The code in a comment is all but unreadable. Please edit your question and add it at the bottom of the question. ThankS1

Comment: Also, the google drive links won't work because access is limited.

Comment: 0
down vote
accept
this is the google drive link, i sure its work

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3Qvtu0pSBzdMTZMRXlBQ1MxZU0 https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gw8N8PZALQ_f4RLojocliOptTuejyiNqNg

Comment: Setting `AltBody` before calling `msgHTML()` achieves nothing because it gets overwritten. Don't post code in external resources; learn how to use SO's formatting controls.

Answer (score 0):

HTML code will be displayed if the content type header, is valid

```
'Content-type: text/html;'
```

but the php code will not be displayed in the mail, you can try to put it in a string and add this before and after the php string

```
<pre>
  <code>

    // your code

  </code>
</pre>
```

Comment: if i write <pre> in my code, its will show my code, i need to show the results from my code